# Reflect sum of column to a label on a WinForm

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to reflect the sum of a column to a label on a WinForm. I don't know what's wrong with this code:

```
private void btnT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = TURKY-PC ; initial 
 catalog = coffeeshopDB ; integrated security = true ; ");            
 SqlCommand cmd;                      
 SqlDataReader dr;        
 cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM (cost) from billTB", cn);             
 cn.Open();       
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
 while (dr.Read())            
   {                
     btnT.Text = dr["cost"].ToString();     
   }         
  dr.Close();      
  cn.Close();       
}
```

The error exception that appears is: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'cost'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to refer to the column by name, you have to name the result of the `SUM`. You also don't need a loop in this case, because you know there's only one row.

```
private void btnT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = TURKY-PC ; initial 
 catalog = coffeeshopDB ; integrated security = true ; ");            
 SqlCommand cmd;                      
 SqlDataReader dr;        
 cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM (cost) as TotalCost from billTB", cn);             
 cn.Open();       
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
 dr.Read();            
 btnT.Text = dr["TotalCost"].ToString();     
 dr.Close();      
 cn.Close();       
}
```